# How to change view in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Have some free time and wanted to try making a game in WPF.
I was wondering, what is the best way of changing the view of a window?
I have made a "main menu" window, with three buttons.. New Game, Continue Game and Exit Game.
When pressing New Game I want the window to go to next "viewstate" for creation of player and such, dont want a new window to pop up. Whats the best way of implementing that.

Comment: is it MVVM application or code behind?

Comment: It is a MVVM application!

Comment: If you create a class for each view state, then you can bind a content control to your Current View State and use a data template to define how its displayed

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is appropriate to use DataTemplates if you want to dynamically switch Views depending on the ViewModel:

```
<Window>
   <Window.Resources>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelA}">
         <localControls:ViewAUserControl/>
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelB}">
         <localControls:ViewBUserControl/>
      </DataTemplate>
   <Window.Resources>
  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>
</Window>
```

If `Window.DataContext` is an instance of `ViewModelA`, then `ViewA` will be displayed and

`Window.DataContext` is an instance of ViewModelB, then ViewB will be displayed.

The best example I've ever seen and read it is made by [Rachel Lim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302677/rachel). [See the example](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/).

Comment: @Micsto see my updated answer(at the bottom). You can see the best example that I've ever seen. I hope it will help to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement every gui you need as an UserControl and load the needed UserControl depending on your current step.

Comment: Slight variation but i would suggest data templates and a content control instead of user controls

Comment: @MikeT ok, i never worked with DataTemplates before. Has just been a fast idea how to get away from seperate windows.

Comment: if you work with WPF i would suggest looking into them  this is good for the basics http://www.wpftutorial.net/datatemplates.html

Comment: In principle I agree but in practice you can't visualize DataTemplates in the DevStudio editor. Not a problem if you use Blend, but I tend to do most of my design writing the XAML by hand with design-time data in which case UserControls are the way to go (albeit with no code-behind of course).