# WPF open a new window without closing the original window

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to develop a software that requires the user to change windows a lot. Instead of opening a new window as a separate entity, I want the new window to replace the old window.

Currently I have this going...

```
Window Jobs_Window = new Jobs();
Jobs_Window.Show();
this.Close();
```

But that opens a new window and closes the old one, which looks messy.

What do I need to do to replace the contents of window 1 with contents of window 2?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33652707/how-to-change-view-in-wpf/33652977#33652977

Comment: What does the version of visual studio have with the question? WPF can be created in versions of visual studio back to 2008. The version of .Net (which WPF relies on) would be a better tag.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using different windows, use one window that will host various user controls via a ContentPresenter.