# WPF: Cannot get View to change dynamically using DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a problem designing my WPF application. I cannot get the Views to change dynamically. The code to call another View is contained in the Views themselves. (I am trying to implement the MVVM pattern. I do not want any code behind in the View xaml files other than assigning the DataContext. An exception is made in the xaml file of the MainWindow).

Basically, I have a Window that contains a UserControl. The UserControl is my View and it is connected to another class serving as ViewModel through Datacontext.

What I want to do is to dynamically change this View/ViewModel pairs contained in the Window.

My idea was define a static property in the ViewModel of the MainWindow and store the ViewModel of the current View in it. Then I planned to use DataTemplates to automatically load a new View whenever a new ViewModel is stored in the static property.

I decided to use a static property because the code to load another ViewModel is contained in the ViewModels itself and I needed a central point with access from everywhere.

So far so good. My initial View loads and displays correctly.

However, pressing a button in that View to load the next View fails although the new ViewModel is correctly assigned to the static property.
I tried several things.

I defined DataTriggers within the ContentControl to react to changes in the static property. No help.

Implementing INotifyProperty and DependencyProperty failed in the end because of the static nature of the property (or I did something wrong).
I just can’t get it to work.

1. Do you have any ideas why this would be?
2. Do you have an idea how I could solve my general problem of dynamically displaying Views without using a static property in my MainWindow. I believe this is causing problems and I have a notion that I am not using the most elegant method. (I do want to maintain the concept of each View holding the code to load any other View)

This is a code fragment from the MainWindow:

```cs
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:StartViewModel}">
            <v:StartView></v:StartView>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:OverviewViewModel}">
            <v:OverviewView></v:OverviewView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding ActiveViewModel}">/ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```cs
DataContext = new MainViewModel();
```

MainViewModel contains the definition for the property ActiveViewModel. The constructor for the class is static. All ViewModels inherit from BaseViewModel class:

```cs
private static BaseViewModel activeViewModel;

static public BaseViewModel ActiveViewModel
{
    get { return activeViewModel; }
    set { activeViewModel = value; }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Bye,
Eskender

Comment: You cannot bind static property with `Path`(unless in .net 4.5 but anyway not like that). Why is `ActiveViewModel` a static property. Make it an instance property that raises `INPC.PropertyChanged` event

Comment: read the link provided in the answer. This is Rachel Lim's tutorial with example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33652707/how-to-change-view-in-wpf/33652977#33652977

Comment: Generally: template and view model class go together. In some cases, you need to use a template selector to choose the template, or just bind to a `Template` property with a converter. It's not clear at all from the question why you're not using one of these standard approaches. Static properties can't raise property-change events that WPF knows about, so they aren't useful for dynamic scenarios. Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem, with a clear description of what exactly you want the code to do that it's not doing now.

Comment: @StepUp thanks, I have read the article before. But it does not apply as in that example the elements and the command code to change the views are contained in the application view model/view. As you can read in my original post I want this to be contained in the different viewmodels themselves. I am not looking for an always present navigation pane as in Rachels example.

Comment: @dkozl I figured that static was not the way to go. I will try to implement INPC again. Thanks